# Exploring / Browsing the promise chain

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

Given a promise object is it possible to browse through the different functions attached to it?

So having this situation (using angular):

```
var promise = $http({ method: 'GET', url: '/random' });
promise.then(function () { console.log('Value1'); });
promise.then(function () { console.log('Value2'); });
promise.then(function () { console.log('Value4'); });
promise.then(function () { console.log('Value5'); });
```

Is there a way to access to:

- Get access to the `n` function
- Add a function in between the current chain

  ```
  var promise = $http({ method: 'GET', url: '/random' });
  promise.then(function () { console.log('Value1'); });
  promise.then(function () { console.log('Value2'); });

  // New insertion:
  promise.then(function () { console.log('Value3'); });

  promise.then(function () { console.log('Value4'); });
  promise.then(function () { console.log('Value5'); });
  ```

Comment: AFAIK, $http is use $q to create promises and $q doesn't support getting the registered function back. Why exactly do you want to have an access to the n-th registered function? May be we could help you solve the problem in an alternative way.

Comment: You need to implemen strategy design pattern to support difference ... stragies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Get access to the `n`th function

No. The only purpose of a promise object is to execute the `then` callbacks when it is resolved. It's not supposed to let you manage the callbacks.
Of course, there may always be an implementation-dependent way to do that.

> Add a function in between the current chain

No. The [Promises/A+ spec](https://promisesaplus.com/) mandates that "*all respective […] callbacks must execute in the order of their originating calls to `then`.*" Therefore, you cannot insert something dynamically.

If you need such functionality, I'd recommend to use an array of things to do that you manage yourself. Then add a single callback to your promise that carries these tasks out in the order that you want.

Answer (score 1):

isn't it possible to put it in your function with an argument ?

Exemple

```
var promise = $http({ method: 'GET', url: '/random' })
.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    promise.resolve('value2');
                })
promise.then(function (value) { 
if(value == 'value1') {
    console.log('Value1'); 
}
if(value == 'value2') {
    console.log('Value2'); 
}



});
```